# s3-lambda integration through java8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have created some buckets in my s3 and a running lambda function. Now what I want is when I upload any image to the bucket say ***source bucket***, then an s3event trigger my lambda function which uploads an encrypted image into the another bucket say- ***destination***.

What my concern here is, how lambda detects the changes in the specific **bucket** or how can I call the s3event of the source bucket only?

Answer (score 0):

For your reference :

[AWS Lambda with S3Event](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/software-development/amazon-aws/tutorial-use-aws-lambda-s3-real-time-data-processing/)

Hope it will help!